I was just awarded the Vox Populi badge erroneously
StackExchange just proudly announced that I just awarded the Vox Populi badge.  However, that's for voting 40 times in a day; I don't think I voted more than 2 or 3 times in a single day, ever.  Did StackExchange just got a glitch?

We just deployed a change that affects the voting badges.  This is why you see a number of these badges being awarded.
For more information about this change, you can see this answer.
Note that there is a bug with Vox Populi only that is awarding too many of them, beyond the expected more for retroactive awards, and a fix is being deployed now.  The erroneous awards there will be cleaned up shortly.

Not a problem; I just thought you'd prefer to be informed...

Just a note, as I just got the banner message with no badge being present: When you remove a badge again, try to also remove the banner which advertises this badge.

@PaŭloEbermann we did.  We removed the badges in step 1 because that also would prevent new erroneous ones being awarded.  Then we removed the notifications.  As of a few minutes ago, everything is completely cleaned up.

Ah, so I just had bad luck to look at the site between both removals.

@PaŭloEbermann indeed.
